# How to find the median of every row in sql (Microsoft SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

For every row, I want to find the median. I have 6 columns and want to find the median of 5 of them

I tried using the percentile_cont, but it does not work because the order by needs a column from the table (even when I used VALUES, it didn't work)

```
id   col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
1     7       5      4      8     10
```

needs to be

```
id   col1   col2   col3   col4   col5   med
1     7       5      4      8     10     7
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Do you ever have duplicates or null values?

Comment: I have added it; Microsoft SQL @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

If the values are different and not-null, you can use a giant `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when ((case when col1 > col2 then 1 else 0 end) +
                   (case when col1 > col3 then 1 else 0 end) +
                   (case when col1 > col4 then 1 else 0 end) +
                   (case when col1 > col5 then 1 else 0 end)
                  ) = 2
             then col1
             when ((case when col2 > col1 then 1 else 0 end) +
                   (case when col2 > col3 then 1 else 0 end) +
                   (case when col2 > col4 then 1 else 0 end) +
                   (case when col2 > col5 then 1 else 0 end)
                  ) = 2
             then col2
             . . . 
        end) as median
from t;
```

In SQL Server, you can also use:

```
select t.*, v.col as median
from t cross apply
     (select col
      from (values (col1), (col2), (col3), (col4), (col5)
           ) v(col)
      order by col1
      offset 2 rows fetch first 1 row only
     ) v;
```